# How to display values from custom managed properties in search results

Tags: search, search-results, managed-metadata

I encountered a problem where I can't show up my Managed properties in the search results form.
I did everything that is written here: [Part 3 - Bonus SharePoint Demo](https://www.metrostarsystems.com/enterprise-it/part-3-bonus-sharepoint-demo/).

Does anybody know what is the reason?

All these Managed properties are searchable, so I can search them, but I can't show them up.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Result Type Rule page. Sometimes new managed properties have to be refreshed here. The page will display a warning and offer a link to update the properties.